# How do I recall a method in main and tell it to run?

Tags: java, methods

I am relatively new to java and for a project I am making a game that will have a 4 player max but at the beginning it asks how many players there are so I don't need all 4 players' scripts in main. I tried to make each player a method and depending on how many players were there that's how many of the players' scripts would be ran.

Basically I don't know how to get the players' methods to run using one command inside of my if statement.

If statement:

```
   if (playerAmount == 1)
{    
       run (player1); // this was my attempt to run the methods xD
}
    else if (playerAmount == 2)
{
       run (player1);
       run (player2); // this was my attempt to run the methods xD
}
    else if (playerAmount == 3)
{
      run (player1);
      run (player2);
      run (player3); // this was my attempt to run the methods xD
}
    else if (playerAmount == 4)
{
      run (player1);
      run (player2); 
      run (player3);
      run (player4); // this was my attempt to run the methods xD
}
```

Methods (there are one of these for each player, this is just for Player 1):

```
    public static void player1()
  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);    

        int p1space = 0;
        int p1health = 100;
        int p1dollars = 0;   

        int rollValue = 0;
        int rollDie = (int) (6*Math.random()+1);


        System.out.println ("Player 1, Please Enter Your Name");
        String p1name = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Would you like a tutorial on how to play? (type yes or no)");
        String tutorial = keyboard.nextLine();
        if ((tutorial .equals ("yes")))
        {
                 System.out.println ("Okay, first the game will have you type roll to roll your die."); 
                 System.out.println ("After that, depending on what number you got on your die, your character will move that far.");
                 System.out.println ("Certain spaces have traps and things to set you back so watch out! There are also spaces that give you bonuses such as extra health.");
                 System.out.println ("That should be enough for you to play. Have Fun! :)");
        }
            while (p1health > 0)
        {
                System.out.println (p1name + " it's your turn!");    
                System.out.println ("Type roll to roll your die");
                String roll = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (roll .equals ("roll"))
                {
                         rollValue = rollDie;
                         p1space = p1space + rollValue;
                         if (p1space == 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println ("START");
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 1) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 1");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 2) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 2");
                                System.out.println ("You found a med pack, +50 Health!");
                                p1health = p1health +50;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 3) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 3");
                                System.out.println ("You find a jetpack, move forward one space");
                                p1space = p1space +1;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 4)
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 4");
                                System.out.println ("You are kidnapped, move back two spaces.");
                                p1space = p1space -2;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 5) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 5");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 6) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 6");
                                System.out.println ("You find $50!");
                                p1dollars = p1dollars +25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 7) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 7");
                                System.out.println ("You find $100!");
                                p1dollars = p1dollars +100;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 8) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 8");
                                System.out.println ("You are shot by an enemy, -25 Health.");
                                p1health = p1health -25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 9) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 9");
                                System.out.println ("You are shot by an enemy, -25 Health.");
                                p1health = p1health -25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 10) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 10");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 11) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 11");
                                System.out.println ("You found a med pack, +25 Health!");
                                p1health = p1health +25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 12) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 12");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 13) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 13");
                                System.out.println ("You find $50!");
                                p1dollars = p1dollars +50;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 14) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 14");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 15) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 15");
                                System.out.println ("You are shot by an enemy, -25 Health.");
                                p1health = p1health -25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 16) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 16");
                                System.out.println ("You find $50!");
                                p1dollars = p1dollars +50;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 17) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 17");

                            }
                            else if (p1space == 18) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 18");
                                System.out.println ("You are shot by an enemy, -25 Health.");
                                p1health = p1health -25;
                            }
                            else if (p1space == 19) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("SPACE 19");
                                 System.out.println ("You are kidnapped, move back a space.");
                                p1space = p1space -1;
                            }
                            else if (p1space >= 20) 
                            {
                                System.out.println ("--------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println ("Congratulations, you made it to the end!");
                                System.out.println ("You made it with:");
                                System.out.println ("     " + p1health + " Health");
                                System.out.println ("     " + p1dollars + " Dollars");
                                p1health = 0;
                            }
                         if (p1dollars >= 300)
                         {
                             System.out.println ("You have enough money to purchase a med pack. Would you like to buy one? (type yes or no)");
                             String medPack = keyboard.nextLine();
                             if (medPack .equals ("yes")) 
                             {
                                    p1health = p1health +50;
                                    System.out.println ("Health +100");
                                    System.out.println ("$750 removed");
                             }
                         }
                }
                else 
                {
                            System.out.println ("I'm sorry I didn't quite get that. Type roll to roll your die.");
                }
        }//end of while
        if (p1health <= 0) // edit in multiplayer
        {
                    System.out.println ("Game Over");
                    System.out.println ("You Died!");
        }
```

}

Comment: 1. "Player" needs to be an object.  That way you have only one method to write, but you can still have one per each player.  2. Use a `for` loop to run each player object once per turn.

Comment: You can't *recall* / undo / pull back a method call. You also can't *recall* / remember a method call. So what interpretation of *recall* are you using here?

Comment: One thing I'm concerned about is the fact that this won't work the way you think. Right now there will be 4 separate games in a row(if you call the methods correctly). You could multithread the players, which is a verry bad idea, and won't work at all with your current code. So before jumping to a multiplayer/multithreaded game, please consider to finnish the game for only one player. As it might be a chalange for you as well at this point.

Comment: Ditto what n247s said:  You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The answers below address the question that you _asked_, but your real problem is that you have not written code that allows the players to take turns.

Comment: You need to look at some tutorials about OO: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2979739/learn-java/java-101-classes-and-objects-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Make player as a class . And class have properties like name of player and methods like startGame. And also you can give the number of player choice to user and create the player object as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you need but you can consider using a runnable interface

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // do your stuff here

        }
    };
```

an then you can run it simply like this

```
myRunnable.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly answering your question. Since your method name is `player1`. To call a method, you write the method name followed by a pair of brackets:

```
myMethod();
```

so your code shall look like:

```
if (playerAmount == 1)
{    
    player1();  //run method for player1
}
```

---

You probably realize there are plenty of code repetition in all your methods (player1(), player2(), player3() & player4()). You may want to learn how to pass arguments to a method. This way, you only need to implement them once:

```
public static void player(int playerNo){

}
```

---

After knowing how to use a method. You may also want to take a look at Java classes where you can actually implement each player as an object instead of a method:

```
class Player{
    public void runScript(){

    }
}
```